# Perform OpenURL action using new AdaptiveCards.Renderer.UWP package

Tags: uwp, adaptive-cards

Before new nuged package with braking changes arrived, I was able to subscribe to actions and defined what app should do for OpenURL action:

```
renderer.Action += Renderer_Action;
..
private void Renderer_Action(AdaptiveCardRenderer sender, AdaptiveActionEventArgs args)
{
    var openUrlAction = args.Action as AdaptiveOpenUrlAction;
    if (openUrlAction != null)
    {...}
}
```

I was not able to find any Events at new **AdaptiveCardRenderer**, how should I listen and react to buttons clicks in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the breaking changes in the latest beta. The new API allows more flexibility by associating the Action event to the rendered card. When you call `RenderAdaptiveCard(...)` you get a `RenderedAdaptiveCard` object back. This object has the OnAction event

Comment: Thanks, works like a magic :) `var uiCard = renderer.RenderAdaptiveCard(card);
                uiCard.Action += SpecifyCardAction;`